# Find "next" row

Tags: mysql

Beginner here. 
I'm using MySQL 5.5.47

I have a "colors" table like below (edit: note that the IDs are not sequential)

```
+---+---------+
|id |color    |
+---+---------+
| 1 | red     |
| 4 | yellow  |
| 6 | blue    |
+---+---------+
```

and a "log" table like below:

```
+---------+----------+
|painting | colorid  | 
+---------+----------+
| a       | 1        |
| b       | 4        |
| c       | 6        |
| d       | 1        |
| e       | 4        |
+---------+----------+
```

I need a query that not only picks automatically the next colorid (in order) when I INSERT the next painting, but also "understand" that the next colorid after "6" (blue) is "1" (red) again (like they're in a loop).

In this example, it would be something like:

```
INSERT into log (painting, colorid) values ('f', [given that the colorid of the last painting (e) was 4, insert here the "next" colorid of the table colors - in this case 6] )
```

And after that

```
INSERT into log (painting, colorid) values ('g', [given that the colorid of the last painting (f) was 6, insert here the "next" colorid of the table colors - and as 6 is the last id, "next" means the first id] )
```

I was toying with the idea of using LEAD, but I think my version can't work it? Other idea involved creating a temporary table with the "colors" table duplicated an use more traditional means like "where id > (last id) limited to 1"

Comment: You can use an `IF()` expression that tests if the next id is higher than `MAX(id)` and returns `MIN(id)` instead.

Comment: I don't see how the data sets relate.